# Angular UI Predictive Text: How to Enter Data not Included in Input Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the [Angular UI's typeahead feature](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) to populate a list. My problem is that I would like it to not restrict what is accepted in the input to only those strings that are in the provided array. The `typeahead-editable` option seems like it would work, but when I put it as an attribute within the input, it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps that is not what it is for?

> (Default: true) - Should it restrict model values to the ones selected from the popup only?

It's not really clear to me what the "popup" is, so maybe it's not the input model as I at first thought.

I can *sorta* work around it by capturing the value in the dropdown on each keypress and saving it to the `$scope` on every keypress event except <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
$scope.freeText = angular.element('#myinput').val();
```

And then when <kbd>enter</kbd> is save the value to `#myinput`'s `ng-model` value, and clear the input

```
$scope.selected = $scope.freeText = '';
```

But the problem is that the full autocompleted text flashes in the input for half a second. How can I use this predictive search so that a user can enter anything he or she wants, and only take the suggested value if desired?

Comment: Can you provide a working Fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what this attribute is for

working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/85SmgdvnSKWfda6QNNQZ?p=preview

```
<h4>Limited - model not set unless input matches available options</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" 
    ng-model="selected" 
    typeahead-show-hint="true" 
    typeahead-focus-first="false"
    typeahead-editable="false" 
    uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

<h4>Not limited - model set as soon as you start typing</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected2 | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected2" 
    typeahead-show-hint="true" 
    typeahead-editable="true" 
    uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

when the option is set to true the model will be set straight away with whatever you type, if it's disabled model will not only not set but the input will be cleared when the input field is blurred

if that isn't working for you the issue most likely lays elsewhere and without real code it's hard to answer

Comment: It seems to bind immediately to the model when I use the attribute `uib-typeahead`, however that makes the predictive functionality fail. it is just a normal input.

Comment: And in your second example, hitting "C", then Enter will get you California, not just "C"

Comment: `My problem is that I would like it to not restrict what is accepted in the input to only those strings that are in the provided array. ` that's exactly the first case. You have the suggestions but you are not limited to them and second example was to show you the difference, when you restrict the values and input value is not matching provided array it will not bind the model, and if you type 'C' you will by default select first element that starts with `C`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not quite seeing it yet. In both examples, when I type "a", then "enter"= "Alabama" autocompletes. I would expect to be able to arrow to the autocompleted sections, but that "Enter" would always favour only what had so far been typed into the input. Is there no way to make it do this?

Comment: Do you have any other ideas to make it perform like this? :)

Comment: That's the default behaviour, if you type and hit enter the first item will be selected, and of course there is a way to not do it, simply add `typeahead-focus-first="false"` I've updated my answer and plunker